# opencv3.1 configure stops

Tags: opencv, cmake

I want to build opencv 3.1.0 with CMake 3.4.3. The problem is that the configure step doesn't finish even after an hour. Is that normal? How can I fix it?

With group:

[image]

All:

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uLLo.png)

Comment: Please don't paste images, but error messages. You can see such a message "no Module named numpy.distutils". So you have to install it.

Comment: Thank you. But it's strange that I can't tick off Python. I think It's not a problem of Python. Everything works well with another computer.